# Requirement for $x$ to be different from $c$ in a theorem regarding limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the following theorem on limits.

$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=l \iff \forall \big\{x_n\big\}_{x\in \mathbb{N}} \mid  x_n\in \operatorname{dom}(f) \wedge x\neq c$  $ \forall x_n\wedge \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = c$

holds that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=l$.

I can't see why the condition $x_n\neq c$ must be true $\forall x_n$. Usually in limits the point to which the $x$ converges is excluded because the function could even not be defined in $c$, but here, since it is required for $x_n$ also to be in $\operatorname{dom}(f)$, isn't it unnecessary?

Maybe there is another reason that I don't see

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is necessary if limit is to mean what we want it to mean.

Let $f(x)=x^2+3$ when $x\ne 0$, and let $f(0)=88$. We want to have $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=3$. If we allow sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_k=0$ for infinitely many $k$ (and $x_k\ne 0$ for infinitely many $k$), then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ will not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer! In your example, why would the limit not exist? I mean also for a sequence with no $x_k=0$ if $lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=0$ than $lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f(0)=88$ and it would be a problem, right?

Comment: If there are no $x_k$ (or only finitely many) with $x_k=0$, then the limit of the $f(x_k)$ is $3$, which is what we want it to be. If instead we have $x_k$ for odd $k$ approaching $0$ but not equal to $0$, and $x_k=0$ for even $k$, then $f(x_n)$ bounces back and forth to being near $3$ and to being $88$, so the limit of the $f(x_n)$ does not exist.

Comment: Ok got it! But why is the limit of $f(x_n)$ equal to $3$ if $x_k\neq 0$? Where is the mistake in $lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=f(0)=88$?

Comment: If the function $f$ is **continuous** at $x=a$, and $(x_n)$ is a sequence with limit $a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(a)$. In fact, this is close to the *definition* of continuity at $x=a$. You are accustomed to dealing mainly with continuous functions, which is probably why you think the limit should be $88$. However, a surprising number of the functions one meets, even in applications, are discontinuous at one point, or even many points. So the limit behaviour that you are accustomed to from your experience with continuous functions no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

In words:

> The limit $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = l$ if and only if for any sequence
>   $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that each $x_n$ is in the domain of
>   $f$, and $x_n \neq c$ for any $n$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = c$ it
>   is true that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = l$.

Consider the following function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if $x = 0$ }\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

See that $$\lim_{x\to 0} ~ f(x) = 0.$$ This is why we exclude $x_n = c$. The usual definition of $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ is that for every $\epsilon> 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x-c| < \delta$, we have $|f(x)-l| < \epsilon$. Here the $0<|x-c|$ part is what you are missing.